# Stop timeline mission - DJI SDK

Tags: dji-sdk

I tried to set timeline missions to the drone with the Mobile SDK. But the stop function after the mission start dont work. Im use the 4.3.2 version.why the mission dont stop?  (I use this function every time a new mission need to start to clear and stop the timeline)

```
public void stopAndClear()
{

    if (missionControl.scheduledCount() > 0)
    {
        if(missionControl.getRunningElement()!=null)
        {

            missionControl.getRunningElement().pause();
            missionControl.getRunningElement().stop();

        }
        missionControl.stopTimeline();
        missionControl.unscheduleEverything();
        missionControl.removeAllListeners();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here a concept of timeline and the task inside concept should be clarified.

The timeline is made of a lot of tasks. When one task is executing, you call the API stop timeline, it would stop AFTER this task is finished instead of stopping the current task. So that's the reason why you couldn't stop the current task especially the current task is waypoint mission or hotpoint mission. 
(We know the getRunningElement().pause SHOULD pause the current mission, but actually
For Pause:
HotpointAction / GotoAction support it.

For Stop:
AircraftYawAction
GimbalAttitutdeAction
GoToAction
HotpointAction
LandOrGoHomeActionBase
RecordVideoAction
ShootPhotoAction
TakeOffAction
TimelineMission

support it.
)

Besides, I suggest you to use our latest SDK version 4.5. It solve some problem for the state machine management in the timeline.

Comment: I don't believe the DJI-provided answer here is correct. Calling stopTimeline() stops execution of the current timeline element immediately, NOT after the element is finished executing. You can download the DJI sample app from Github to validate this.